# Plot a CDF from a frequency table in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some frequency data:

```
Rank Count
A    34
B    1
C    1
D    2
E    1
F    4
G    112
H    1 
 ...
```

in a dictionary:

```
d = {"A":34,"B":1,"C":1,"D":2,"E":1,"F":4,"G":112,"H":1,.......}
```

The letters represent a rank from highest to lowest (A to Z), and the number of time I observed the rank in the dataset.

How can I plot the cumulative distribution function given that I already have the frequencies of my observations in the dictionary? I want to be able to see the general ranking of the observations. For example: 50% of my observations have a rank lower than E.

I have been searching for info about this but I always find ways to plot the CDF from the raw observations but not from the counts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to plot a bar plot with the rank on the x axis and the cdf on the y axis?

```
u = u"""Rank Count
A    34
B    1
C    1
D    2
E    1
F    4
G    112
H    1"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)
df["Cum"] = df.Count.cumsum()/df.Count.sum()
df.plot.bar(x="Rank", y="Cum")

plt.show()
```

[image]